# Cannot run anacron while it seems to be installed (Debian 10)

Tags: debian, apt, anacron

I'd like to setup a job using anacron on my desktop PC running Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

The `anacron` package seems to be installed properly: running `sudo apt install anacron` returns

```
anacron is already the newest version (2.3-28). 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`man anacron` opens the man page properly, but surprisingly, `anacron -h` returns

```
-bash: anacron: command not found
```

What could be possibly going on ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe `/usr/sbin` is not in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debian package `anacron` [installs the executable `anacron` as `/usr/sbin/anacron`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/anacron/filelist).

If `/usr/sbin` is not part of your `PATH` variable's value, then you would have to specify the full path to the utility to execute it, like so:

```
$ /usr/sbin/anacron -h
```

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda♦ and @Bodo, that was it !